# Python3.7 Convert comma delimited datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-datetime

I am reading a date column in a postgresql DB. I would like to convert it from below reading into YYYY-MM-DD (this is how it is entered into the DB originally).
What is the best approach to do this?

Code:

```
dataReading = cursor.fetchall()
print(dataReading[1])
```

Output:

```
(datetime.date(2016, 1, 5),)
```

Comment: what library are you using, `psycopg2`?

Comment: Correct! psycopg2

Comment: Thats the internal representation, `print(dataReading[1][0])` should print a well-formatted date

Comment: This solved my question! Thank you.
print(dataReading[1][0])

Comment: would you rather solve this in the database or on the Python side?